# Writing bytes in files the right way in C / C++ [Endianess]

Tags: c++, c, fwrite, endianness

I'm writing a program that creates MIDI files, and I'm trying to write the midi messages on a file.

I tested first all the way to create file from zero using the function `fputc()` and inputting byte per byte all the file, and it went well.

The problem came when I tried to write more than one byte at the same time (e.g. writing a `short int` or an `int` into the file), because the function `fwrite()` put the bytes backwards.

**For example:**

```
FILE* midiFile;

midiFile = fopen("test.mid", "wb");

short msg = 0x0006;

fwrite(msg, sizeof(msg), 1, midiFile);

fclose(midifile);
```

The output written int the file its 0x06 the 0x00, and not the expected: 0x00,0x06.

I read about that, and find that it's caused by the *endianness*; my Intel processor uses *little endian* so it writes variables *bigger than 1 byte* backwards (compared to a *big endian* machine).

I still need to correct that and write the bytes the way I want to develop my program.

My compiler doesn't identify functions like `htonl()` or similar (I don't know why) but I'm asking a way to do it, or how to write `short`'s and `int`'s on char arrays (especially `short`'s).

Comment: Unless you can provide a link to the specification of that "C/C++" languages, please pick one of C **or** C++. They are different languages! And there are more potential issues with your code. To transfer/store internal data, use proper _marshalling_ and use types of _fixed size_.

Comment: @Olaf, in this particular case the answer would be the same, so c and c++ tags are approriate. Otherwise you would be saying that no more than one tag is allowed for the question.

Comment: @SergeyA: Disagreed. Proper marshalling can be much simplified using an OOP approach which would have to be implemented very different in C and C++.

Comment: You can normalize endianess issues using the [`htonl()`, `ntohl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) functions.

Comment: @Olaf, OP needs know marshalling. He just needs to write data in big endian format for MIDI.

Comment: One of the terms to look for is 'serialization' (another is marshalling) — converting data into a format suitable for transmission over a wire, or storage in a file, or the converse, in a suitably platform-neutral way.  'Right' and 'Wrong' aren't helpful terms in this context; big-endian and little-endian and 'network byte order' are more useful terms.  You need to find out what the MIDI standard defines as correct, and then take steps to ensure that your code matches that specification (on both input and output).

Comment: @SergeyA: "..." - which is commonly called "marshalling" or "serialisation". Typical MIDI data includes more than a single `uint16_t` and can be best represented by a `struct` resp. `class`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not all network protocols use big endian actually. (Not sure if that's true for MIDI, though).

Comment: Don't use the `short` data type.  The `short` data type can be any amount of bytes as long as it meets the minimum capacity.  For specific lengths, use `uint16_t`.

Comment: Midi format is [bigendian](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html). Read **one byte at a time**, and process it in context, you won't go wrong. You don't need any swapping nonsense.

Comment: Remember that MIDI is a serial byte stream and so your file should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Either write the bytes you want in order, one at a time...

or swap the bytes before you write them.

```
uint8_t msbyte = msg >> 8;
uint8_t lsbyte = msg & 0xFF;

uint8_t buffer[2];
// Big Endian
buffer[0] = msbyte;
buffer[1] = lsbyte;

/* Little endian
buffer[0] = lsbyte;
buffer[1] = msbyte;
*/
fwrite(&buffer[0], 1, sizeof(buffer), midiFile);
```

Swapping bytes:

```
uint16_t swap_bytes(const uint16_t value)
{
  uint16_t result;
  result = value >> 8;
  result += (value & 0xFF) << 8;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: So clear demonstration. Thanks! In the first line, when doing `msg >> 8`, is it assumed that `msg` is 2Bytes(such as typical `short`)? What happens if `msg` is not 2Bytes? Do we need `(msg >> 8) & 0xFF` instead?